# Simplest way to create a HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I need a dummy window in MSVC++, this will never be visible and is created even before the app's main window. It's required by a rendering engine. So I'd rather not have to register a class if possible.

For testing it would be better to make it visible to prove it is there - can I use a static or a button or something? I've been trying with CreateWindow() but while I am getting a return value, nothing visible is appearing.

Comment: "required by a rendering engine" suggests that this window is used to create a render context. Is that so? In that case, you should preferrably create a window of the same class as your application window's. Otherwise, you have no guarantee that a) you can create a context at all, and b) that the context will be compatible with the one you use later. You'll have to register a class anyway for your main window, so it doesn't "cost extra", really.

Comment: I am not creating my own main window, so I have no class to re-use... and this window will be used as a dummy render-window by the engine... never actually rendered to.

Comment: I second this because I often run into situations that I need a dummy hWnd. For instance I need an hwnd for some win32 font API, in order to blit the font into a 2d memory array without showing it to the window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I submit my own test code for critique:

```
HWND dummyHWND = ::CreateWindowA("STATIC","dummy",WS_VISIBLE,0,0,100,100,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
::SetWindowTextA(dummyHWND,"Dummy Window!");
```

It seemed to work...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why not? It _is_ an answer to the question and there is nothing wrong (in principle) with answering your own question on stackoverflow.

Comment: It is my answer to my question - after asking the question I tried it and it worked. By critique I mean it's open for improvements or whatever.

Comment: The return type of CreateWindow is void. CreateWindowEx returns an HWND

Answer (score 2):

After CreateWindow you need to call ShowWindow to make it visible.

Comment: Or specify the `WS_VISIBLE` flag.

Answer (score 1):

In the first tutorial of [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01) they describe carefully what you need to do to set up an OpenGL rendering context, and the creation of a window (and HWND) is a part of it. If you need it for something else than OpenGL context I believe the code they present can be easily adopted.

Comment: This is kind of what I want, but isn't there a default 'plain empty window' class I can use?

Comment: I haven't seen there. But I think it is easier to remove unwanted code rather than create new one. That's why I posted.

Comment: Please don't cite NeHe

Comment: @itzJanuary Why not? Also note, this is a 7 year old question/answer.