# Action is performed only after returning from function

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, hwnd

I got a little problem that i have some code written in a function that should display some pictures on a board, and i can see the pictures only after the whole function finishes. Here it is:

*(in the following code, `pictures` is an array of `PictureBoxes`)*

```
void static paint_path(ArrNode* node)
{
    list<int> head=(NG->game->getboard()).getcolored();
    int place=-1;
    while(head.size())
    {
        place=head.back();
        head.pop_back();
        if(node[place].color == white)
            pictures[place]->ImageLocation = "white-.bmp"; /*THIS LINE*/
        else if(node[place].color == black)
        {
            pictures[place]->ImageLocation = "black-.bmp"; /*AND THIS LINE*/
        }
    }
}
```

I need those 2 lines /*THIS LINE*/ /*and THIS LINE*/ to be performed in time, and not only after the function finishes. In fact, the pictures are really shown only after the function that called to a function that called to this function returns. Why is that?!

Thank you

***EDIT***

I progressed by including `Windows.h` in `stdafx.h`, and `stdafx.h` in `Form1`.
Now, as **ScottMcP-MVP** suggested, i'm trying to use `UpdateWindow().` I read that `UpdateWindow()` takes a variable of type HWND. So i defined the following in my function: (definition taken from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231186/simplest-way-to-create-a-hwnd))

```
HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindowA("STATIC","dummy",WS_VISIBLE,0,0,100,100,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
::SetWindowTextA(hwnd,"Window!");
```

and called `UpdateWindow(hwnd);`

But i keep getting an error:

`Error  15  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001D) "extern "C" int __stdcall UpdateWindow(struct HWND__ *)" (?UpdateWindow@@$$J14YGHPAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __clrcall GUI::Form1::paint_path(struct b_node *)" (?paint_path@Form1@GUI@@$$FCMXPAUb_node@@@Z) C:\...\GUI.obj`

Any further help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You bought yourself a lot more trouble by following Scott's advice.  Just use `pictures[place]->Update();`

Comment: GENIUES!!! Put it as an answer i'll choose it. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the delay is that while the function is executing the painting code is not executing. After the function returns message processing resumes, and will process WM_PAINT. You can call the UpdateWindow API to force an immediate paint during your function.

Comment: OK i read about UpdateWindow and i found that i should include the file `Winuser.h` or `Windows.h`. But visual studio (2010) isn't letting me include them. I get errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using? What GUI library are you using? What error do you get?

Comment: Language C++ , GUI C++ , 
Errors when adding `Windows.h` : `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant' C:\...\include\windef.h` , `error C2059: syntax error : 'constant' C:...\include\windef.h` and some more.

Comment: The UpdateWindow solution applies to C/C++ WinAPI apps. You appear to be using C++/CLI with the Winforms GUI library. Try adding a Winforms tag to your question in hopes of getting a more relevant answer.